# Java class variables equal same value

Tags: java, class, variables

I am preparing for a certification exam and I don't understand this code:

Main:

```
public class TestStudent {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student bob = new Student();
        Student jian = new Student();
        bob.name = "Bob";
        bob.age = 19;
        jian = bob;
        jian.name = "Jian";
        System.out.println("Bob's Name: " + bob.name);
    }
}
```

Class:

```
public class Student {
    public String name = "";
    public int age = 0;
    public String major = "Undeclared";
}
```

Why does this output "Bob's Name: Jian"?

Bob.name was never set to Jian. Obviously it must be because "jian = bob;" but i thought that would only set jian variables to the same as bob.  What is this concept called and where is it explained in java tutorials?

Comment: I can answer this in 5 minutes. Thank you all for your many helpful answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assignments in Java do not copy objects, they copy references. After this assignment

```
jian = bob;
```

your `jian` is no longer pointing to the `Student` object that you have allocated and assigned to  `jian`, it's the same as `bob`, creating an *alias* to the same object. The original `jian` is now irretrievably lost, becoming eligible for garbage collection.

The following assingment

```
    jian.name = "Jian";
```

overwrites the name in the `bob` variable through its `jian` alias, leading to the result that you see.

Comment: So whether I call the variable from that point on (jian = bob;), jian or bob it references the same dataset regardless?

Comment: @Quinma Yes, this is correct. After the assignment, both variables "point" to the same `Student` object.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the code `"jian = bob;"
You changed the reference of the bob object and set it to jian. 
Then setting jian.name = "Jian" Also changes the bob object

Answer (score 1):

now your `jian` object reference points on the same memory part as object reference `bob`, so if you change one of them - it will affect both of them, cause now they are the same object.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `bob` and `jian` (like all non-primitive variables in java) are references (pointers to objects) rather than objects.  So when you say `jian = bob;`, that makes `jian` point at the same object as `bob`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a fundamental concept in Java: all *object variables* - that is, objects such as `bob` and `jian` which represent instances of Java Classes - are *references*.  This concept is also referred to as *pointers* in languages such as C.

This means that your variable `bob` does not, conceptually, hold the values of the `name`, `age` and `major` fields, instead it *points* to a location in memory which holds the data.  Accordingly, when you use an assignment operator (that's the `=` symbol) with object reference variables, you are simply changing which part of memory that variable points to.  So the line:

```
bob = jian
```

means that the variable `bob` now refers to the *same* area of memory as `jian`, and anything you do in one will be reflected in the other.

This leaves an interested question of what has happened to the area of memory which holds Bob's data.  Since we no longer have a reference to it, it is no longer possible for us to get hold of it, even though it still exists somewhere in memory (although Java will soon notice and clear it up - known as *garbage collection*).

Anyway, this sort of concept is better expressed diagrammatically, so I suggest looking [at the official Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html) or [this tutorial](http://www.learn-java-tutorial.com/JavaObjects.cfm#References).

Answer (score 0):

The variables bob and jian are object references. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html

This article contains an example similar to yours: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=174371&seqNum=4